# python add array of hours to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

import timedelta as td
I have a date time and I want to add an array of hours to it.

i.e.

```
Date[0]
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)

Date[0] + td(hours=9)
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 9, 0)

hrs = [1,2,3,4]
Date[0] + td(hours=hrs)
```

But obviously it is not supported.

Date array above is a giant array of size 100X1 and I want to add hrs = [1,2,3,4] to each row of Date to get a datetime array of size 100x4. So, a for loop is not going to work in my case.

Comment: why isn't a for loop going to work?..

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested *list comprehension* and [`.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace). Sample for a list with 2 datetimes:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: l = [datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0)]

In [3]: hours = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [4]: [[item.replace(hour=hour) for hour in hours] for item in l]
Out[4]: 
[[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 2, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 3, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 4, 0)],
 [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 2, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 3, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 4, 0)]]
```

As a result a 2x4 list of lists.